# What did the Author mean by saying "Bluetooth does not provide native user authentication."

Tags: authentication, bluetooth

I was reading an article on Bluetooth security (see citation below), and in the introduction the authors writes:

"Bluetooth specifications provide for three basic security
services: -

Authentication: verifying the identity of
communicating devices based on their Bluetooth
device address.

**Bluetooth does not provide native
user authentication.** "

What do they mean by that? I had trouble understanding what they were trying to say by "native user authentication".

Tsira, Vikethozo & Nandi, Gypsy. (2014). Bluetooth Technology: Security Issues and Its Prevention. International Journal of Computer Technology & Applications. 5. 1833.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that if you connect Bluetooth device A to device B then device B can be sure that A is really A, but cannot tell that the user of A is who he or she claims to be. If you need B or the user of B to be certain of the identity of the user of A then you will need an additional layer i.e. one that is not native to Bluetooth.